# Django - cannot retrieve username in admin after form submission

Tags: python, django

I have a form to when a user makes a form submission I need the current logged in user to automatically populate in the django admin. I would like the current user's username to populate in the column where it says `User` in the django admin. Screenshot attached.

How do I execute that correctly with my current code?

The Custom User Model I’m using is located in `from users.models import CustomUser` if that helps.

Any help i gladly appreciated, Cheers

[image]

## user_profile/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from user_profile.forms import HomeForm
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

from user_profile.models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser


# Register models here.

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'created', 'updated', 'get_username']
    list_filter = ['name', 'zip_code', 'created', 'updated',]

    def get_username(self, obj):
        if obj.user is not None:
            return obj.user.username
        return '-'
    get_username.short_description = 'User'

admin.site.register(Listing, UserProfileAdmin)


#user_profile/models
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from users.models import CustomUser

class Listing (models.Model):

#    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    cc_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    cc_expiration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    cc_cvv = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    objects = ListingManager()

    def get_username(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Listing.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=CustomUser)
```

## user_profile/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import HomeForm
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from avatar.forms import PrimaryAvatarForm, DeleteAvatarForm, UploadAvatarForm
from avatar.models import Avatar
from avatar.signals import avatar_updated, avatar_deleted
from avatar.utils import (get_primary_avatar, get_default_avatar_url,
                          invalidate_cache)


def change_view(request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None)
    user_profile = Listing.objects.all
    user = request.user

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = HomeForm()

    context = {
        'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile 
    }

    return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)
```

## user_profile/forms.py

```
import os

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.forms import widgets
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat

from avatar.conf import settings
from avatar.models import Avatar
from .models import Listing


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

#    user = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CVV', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    created = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CVV', 'class': 'form-control'}))    
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full Name', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    address = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    zip_code = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Zipcode', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    cc_number = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Credit Card', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    cc_expiration = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Expiration Date', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    cc_cvv = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CVV', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number']
```

## html

```
 <form role="form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.errors }}   
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.address }}
{{ form.zip_code }}
{{ form.mobile_number }}
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-success btn-round btn-extend" type="submit" value="Submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite-outline6"></i>Submit</button>
</form>
```

## settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether your code is correct or not. If it's working fine, this would also fine :)

```
def change_view(request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None)
    user_profile = Listing.objects.all
    user = request.user

    if form.is_valid():
        listing_instance = form.save()  # "this will return the 'Listing' instance"
        listing_instance.user = user # assign 'user' instance
        listing_instance.save() # calling 'save()' method of model
        form = HomeForm()

    context = {
        'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile
    }

    return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)
```

Comment: PERFECT. THANK YOU MY FRIEND!

Answer (score 0):

I think You just have to `register` your user model at the `admin.py`..
like..

`admin.site.register(CustomUser)`

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, When I added that I received `django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model CustomUser is already registered` Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: do `admin.site.unregister(CustomUser)` before `admin.site.register(CustomUser)`